# Particle between city and prefecture?

Tags: word-order

I'm trying to say, "I went to Oarai Town in Ibaraki Prefecture last year."

> 昨年に大洗町茨城県に行きました。

Is there supposed to be a comma or particle (perhaps で) between the city and prefecture? Please let me know if there is a better way to write this sentence.

Comment: Do they teach you to say 「昨年に」 in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language?  I ask because I see that a lot here.  It is definitely just 「昨年」 for us native speakers.

Comment: @l'électeur From the textbooks I've seen, I get the impression that students are typically taught "whenever you use a 'time word', always add に as a particle", and only later learn that not using に is often more natural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't comment yet on the site (reputation) but the Japanese addressing system goes from largest to smallest. I would change the order and use の but I'll defer to anyone else with more experience.

> 昨年に茨城県の大洗町に行きました。

Comment: The の  is probably not necessary... I always see it written as Prefecture + City.

Comment: @OrlandoB.Manta It actually sounds more natural with 「の」 here.   In address writing, however, 「の」 is not used.

Comment: Conversationally, I think it is more usual to drop the 県; just 「茨城の大洗」.